# Payment Automation

Tags: recurring-contributions

1) Is There any way to make a client payment contribution automatically on the due date so he/she does not have to do that manually.

2) Or can we setup a monthly standing order of £50 and every month by CRON the system will create these donations for her against that person.

Thanks In Advance

Comment: Please explain what research you have already done on this. Which of the community resources have you read? Did you google "civicrm recurring contributions"? Please make an effort to show you have made an effort.

Answer (score 2):

Aman, you will want to look at  Recurring Contributions.  If this is not what you are looking for please clarify your question.

Thanks,
Steve